# Extjs - init class atttribute and get class name

Tags: extjs, grid

i have simple 'gridpanel' with 'tbar' like this

```
Ext.define('Ext.abc.grid', {
     extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',  
     type:1,    
     tbar:[
        {    
        text:'title1',
        class :'a1',                
        handler:function(type){
             if (this.type == 1) { // button not 1
            Ext.query(".a2").setDisabled(false);
                 }
        },{
            text:'title2',
        class :'a2',                
        handler:function(type){
             if (this.type == 1) { // button not 1
            Ext.query(".a1").setDisabled(false);
             }
        }
     ]
    });
```

i try to add class (a1) to button title1 and the some for title2, but when i get class like

```
Ext.query(".a1").setDisabled(false);
```

it's not working

and i can't get type = 1 when i click title1, i using this.type but results is 'button' not 1

How can i do that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got several problems here.

First, see sha's answer, you're getting an array as the result of your call to `Ext.query(...)`.

Second, `Ext.query` returns [`Ext.dom.Element`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element), which are Ext objects for representing actual DOM elements like div, img, etc. What you want to access, your buttons, are [`Ext.Component`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Component). You can query components with [`Ext.ComponentQuery`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery).

Then, you're using `this.type` in your button handler functions, but when these method get called, `this` will be the button itself (this can be customized using the [`scope`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-scope) option), not the container on which you set `type: 1`.

Edit:

Here's how to make your example work:

```
Ext.define('Ext.abc.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel'

    ,type: 1

    ,tbar: [{
        text: 'title1'
        ,itemId: 'button1'

        // just FYI, here the scope (this) is the window, because we are not
        // in a method
        ,scope: this // so this doesn't work

        ,handler: function() {
            // using ComponentQuery to get a reference to the other components
            var grid = this.up('grid'), // by xtype
                tbar = this.up(), // by relative position
                button2 = tbar.down('#button2'); // by itemId
            if (grid.type === 1) {
                button2.disable();
            }
        }
    }, {
        text: 'title2'
        ,itemId: 'button2'
        ,handler: function() { ... }
    }]
});
```

Now, reading your mind, here's what I think you actually want to do:

```
Ext.define('Ext.abc.Grid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel'

    ,type: 1

    ,tbar: [{
        text: 'title1'
        ,itemId: 'button1'
    }, {
        text: 'title2'
        ,itemId: 'button2'
    }]

    // reading in your mind, I guess, this is what you really want to do:
    ,initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent();

        if (this.type === 1) {
            this.down('#button2').disable();
        } else {
            this.down('#button1').disable();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Furthermore, due to poor indentation, you don't realize your code is broken. Your closing brace at `},{` doesn't match the first button object, but the handler function...

Comment: sorry, i re-typing wrong, but i using:  text:'title1',
   class :  'a1',
   scope: this,
   handler:function(){
    alert(this.type);} but it's not working

Comment: thanks u, it's working with: alert(this.up('grid').type);. But i want add class not id, because i create many new Ext.abc.Grid. It's duplication. I using Ext.ComponentQuery.query(".a1").setDisabled(false); but it's not working?

Comment: You're right, explicit ids are the root of all evils. [itemId](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-cfg-itemId)s, on the other hand are cool, and can be duplicated across the application, because they are interpreted relatively to their parent containers (see the doc).

Comment: i found a solution like: Ext.ComponentQuery.query('button#a1')[0].setDisabled(false); :)

Answer (score 0):

Ext.query returns you an array http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext-method-query

You can't simply call `setDisabled()` on an array. You need to loop through all elements.

Comment: var els=Ext.query(".btnEdit"); but alert(els.length); is 0.<br> what about my 'type'? any ideal

Comment: Look at docs for handler function for button: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.button.Button-cfg-handler - first argument to the handler is `button` object. button.type is not something that you need to compare.